# exim4 redirect router, fallback if redirected delivery fails

Tags: email, email-server, exim

I run an exim4 instance that is the primary MX for my domain and receives email from the public Internet. Mail for my users is forwarded on to other email addresses - I use the `redirect` router and alias files to achieve this.

Sometimes, the email server receiving the forwarded message rejects it. In this case, exim bounces the message back to the original sender.

I would prefer that if the redirected delivery fails, exim does not cause the whole delivery to fail, but instead falls back to an alternative router, such as to make a local delivery.

Is this possible, and how can I configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`redirect` is not intended for mass forwarding. May be you have to setup the `begin rewrite` section in the config?

```
begin rewrite
*@first.domain.tld  $local_part@second.domain.tld       Eh
```

Here all the messages for `first.domain.tld` will be rewrited and recipient address will be substituted by `second.domain.tld`. Then your routers relay messages to the right box.

Other possible situation is that you have two servers that should be responsive for the same local_domains. In that case you have to add `manualroute` router that retransmit incoming message to the other server - accordingly to the set of conditions.

Comment: You didn't answer the fallback aspect of the question. how to add a fallback if one router fails (say delivery to my home machine fails for 4h, then i want it to be delivered locally to a maildir which is synchronized with via cronjob to my home machine. that way i could read all emails even if my home machine is down)